# DPCPP+MPI file not found with angled include

Tags: c++, algorithm, mpi, hpc, intel-oneapi

I am using Intel OneAPI base kit and HPCToolkit to run a simple MPI and DPCPP program. The program can be found here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/compile-and-run-mpi-programs-using-dpcpp-language.html

The program is compiled as in the website:

```
$ export I_MPI_CXX=dpcpp
$ mpiicpc -fsycl -std=c++17 -lsycl -ltbb main.cpp -o dpc_reduce
```

However I get the error as “algorithm “ file not found with  include; use “quotes” instead. I tried using quotes but I get the same error. Any help please.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you got?

Comment: And, if `mpiicpc` works like `gcc`, library should be placed after file to compile, so something like `$ mpiicpc -fsycl -std=c++17 main.cpp -o dpc_reduce -lsycl -ltbb`

Comment: The question rather suggests an issue with `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: This is a C++ question. I've updated the tags for you.

Comment: @Mathieu “algorithm “ file not found with include; use “quotes” instead.  This is the error message

Comment: We can run the program successfully on Ubuntu 20.04 and dpcpp 2022.2 version. Could you please provide the Os details,dpcpp version, and error log to reproduce your issue?